# Auxiliary CSS-site down

Tags: bug

For about 12 hours, reading SO on a mobile device (anonymously) gives me the CSS-free version, thus pure html.

The same happens (currently) on programmers. On  MSO, AU, AE and the general SE, everything is fine.